# Set spring property for every request

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have a spring bean that I get like this within a method-

```
repAppCaller = CensusFileSpringUtils.getBean(CensusFileWfConstants.Spring.Bean.REP_CALLER);
```

but this bean has a property that is set just 1 time and not for every request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I do not understand your question, try to clarify it, but I think you have to use [prototype scope](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes) for creating new instance per call, by default in spring installed singleton scope.

Comment: Yes, I wanted a prototype. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the instance of `repAppCaller` that is obtained *must* expose a method like `setProperty(...)` to enable you to have such a requirement.

If so, you can use [`OncePerRequestFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html) to fetch the request property you need to and then assign it using `repAppCaller.setProperty(...)` to be used in later phases of *the same* request.